# Problem with Index of in Substring array

Tags: c#, asp.net

ProfilePageList is the string array with each string containing pageID, PageName and PageContent separated by group of characters (#$%). This is a ASP.NET application using C#

```
            foreach (string item in ProfilePageList)
            {
                string PageContent = ""; string PageName = ""; string PageID = "";

                *** > This part is wrong. Help me here ***

                PageID = item.Substring(0, item.IndexOf('#$%') + 2);
                PageContent = item.Substring(item.IndexOf('#$%') + 1);
                PageName = item.Substring(0, item.IndexOf('#$%'));


                callsomefunction(PageID , PageName, PageContent);  
            }
```

Input string is `Helloo#$%<p>How are you??</p>#$%74396`

I dont understand how to use this substring. Can someone help me Please!! Thanks a lot in advance..

Comment: you should prefer to use string.Empty over ""

Comment: @Remo: Why are you using #$% as a separator @Muad'Dib: It makes no practical difference. In fact I think there is no difference at all, at least in the newer versions of .NET.

Comment: I have given #$% as a separator because, pageContent will have all of the characters like , . = ! etc. SO just to avoid bad confrontation, i used combined characters.

Comment: @Remo: What if I type #$% in the page content

Comment: @Matti: Haah! So tell me how can i do this?? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at these:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring(v=vs.71).aspx

and

http://csharp.net-informations.com/string/csharp-string-substring.htm

But I think what you're trying to do is something like this:

```
string[] substrings = inputString.Split("#$%");
```

Anyway, the data structure you are using -- cramming data into strings -- is rather convoluted. Why not just use proper objects?